# Importing a variable, which is user inputted, from another file

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for help.

For the purpose of the question, i have created a small test program. I am trying to find a way to import an input that is saved in a variable from one Python file, into another file. I am able to pass a standard variable, but not one that has been inputted by a user.

When i try to do this it runs the file from the start again, which is not what i want *See below*

I want to Run test.py first

**test.py**

```
password = input ("Please enter your password")

import test2
```

**test2.py**

```
from test import password

print (password)
```

**output below**

```
Please enter your password:Fred
Please enter your password Fred
Fred
```

What i am trying to do is to pass an input without it running the file again. I hope this makes sense.

I basically want the second file to display the input

Comment: test.py is executed twice because of your circular import. If you create a third module that the other two import from, you'll have broken that circular import. You could also pass the information as an argument in a function call (ie fully load module, get function, call function with information)

Comment: The most straight-forward way of fixing it is to remove the import from test.py and then run test2.py - importing a module probably shouldn't have a side-effect of printing anyway.. but then again you'd still be printing with the `input` function. Whichever file is your entry point should be the one deciding what happens, let any other modules be support

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. This is just a small test program to try and get the idea across, if i am able to print the vaiable, i can use it. The actual program asks you to create a username in one file (Signup) and then it users that variable (Username) in another python file.

Comment: Whatever isn't the entry-point file, have it present its functionality as functions. For example `def ask_user_for_password():` or `def do_stuff_with_password(password):` (and only one-directional imports, nothing circular)